# Serving sweets at an oral qualifying exam

Tags: thesis-committee, qualifying-exam

What are your opinions on serving sweets at an oral exam. The only people attending would be the exam committee members.

For my master's degree I was at a school where it was customary for everyone to bring cookies and coffee at oral exams or presentations. However, now I'm at a school where generally nothing is served at seminars unless the speaker is visiting from another university.

My lab-mates mostly only brought some bottled water to the exam for the committee members. One, also made a pot of coffee and brought it to the exam.

My exam will be later in the afternoon and I know that two of my committee members will have been in another exam prior to the start of mine. I feel like it would be nice if I brought a box of candy or something along with water and maybe coffee for refreshment. I'm a little worried about them getting impatient or in a bad mood as the exam draws on. One of my lab-mates however thinks that I would be taking it too far and I may offend the committee members.

What are your thoughts?

EDIT: this was marked as a possible duplicate. I believe it is different because the other question was referring to a defense where anyone could attend. Providing refreshments in such a case could be seen as an attempt to get more people to attend. In my case no one was allowed to attend and I was afraid that a committee member could see this as me giving "gifts" in hopes of swaying them.

Comment: Opinion about serving sweets? I find this question a mockery of the tags applied.

Comment: I think most faculty would not object to being offered some cookies; I think it's cute. That said, make sure that your presentation is impeccable because otherwise, one might grumble that your priorities are wrong.

Comment: While not an exact duplicate: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/7264/929 and I stand by my answer *everybody likes cookies/biscuits*

Comment: I think you should ask your advisor what's appropriate.  For mine, I did quite a range of appetizers & cookies (it was open to anyone at the school), but then my fallback plan if I didn't pass was to work as a chef :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it appropriate to bring coffee and cookies to a PhD defense?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7245/is-it-appropriate-to-bring-coffee-and-cookies-to-a-phd-defense)

Comment: I think the question linked by @StrongBad is a fairly good match.

Comment: Yeah, I found that question before posting. However, I felt that for a PhD defense since other people will be invited to attend it could be interpreted differently. At my qualifying exam no one other than the committee members is allowed to attend.

Comment: Here's an update: I ended up bringing a box of chocolate and making a pot of coffee. They all loved the idea :)

Answer (score 5):

Over here in the UK, we do not provide anything as a candidate, if necessary the research group's secretary knows what to do. Anyhow, I would agree with your friend, I would provide only water, and then if applicable I would ask a senior lecturer (such as your supervisor or head of group) in the research group to invite the examiner(s) for tea/coffee/beer and/or lunch.

Comment: Thanks. I'm studying in the US. My last school was also in the US.

Comment: @Hadi Ok then, add the beer as well :-)